# If Else with ("TextBox" & a)

Tags: vb.net

I want to have my textbox loop and check if it already has 0 value in it. I could run the program but it always stop when its in the 1st line(of code given). I cant detect any errors. I already looked for an answer in the internet but I couldn't find one. Thank you in advance!

```
    If ("TextBox" & a) = 0 Then
        z = z + 1
    End If
```

I always received this error:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`

Additional information: Conversion from string `TextBox2` to type `Double` is not valid.

Comment: of course, You try to check two different variable types... read again `Additional information` and `unhandled exception` there are errors ... provide more code... btw. You can't get `TextBox` controls by that way... You have to loop trough container control (may be form, or where are placed)... try to find something like `For Each control In Me.Controls: If TypeOf control is TextBox Then : Dim txt As TextBox=control: If IsNumeric(txt.Text) Then : If CDec(txt.Text) = 0 Then z+=1 ...` and so on.

Comment: That will not compile.  "TextBox" is a string, `&` will concat whatever `a` is to it, but the result can never be 0

Comment: Well, we don't know what is "a", "z".. and generally, how do you expect `"TextBox" & a` to be equal to "0"? you already have "TextBox" in it. Concatinated to whatever `a.ToString` returns. How can it be equal to "0"???

Comment: I think we're going to need a little more code to go on here. Are you attempting to loop through multiple textboxes? Even so, you check the value of a TextBox using it's Text property.

Comment: @nelek Thank you! It worked. :) .. Thank you for all your answers!